# Pyspark: concatenate items in a list in RDD to a single string With Map\FlatMap function

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, flatmap

I have this `RDD` made from `Parquet file` :

`[Row(id=12, anchor_text=[Row(id=23040, text='political philosophy'), Row(id=99232, text='movement'), Row(id=48518, text='Oxford University Press')]), Row(id=13, anchor_text=[Row(id=357356, text='Stanford'),Row(id=9508, text='Encyclopaedia Stanford'), Row(id=13195327, text='Encyclopaedia Archives')])]`

I want to get this result:

```
[12, ['political philosophy movement Oxford University Press'],[13, ['Stanford Encyclopaedia Archives']]]
```

and then create a RDD df with two colums, one for the integer and one for the string

Comment: Your example is not a valid python list. Can you fix that ?

Comment: I changed the example

Comment: Just a map and join should do. Try `rdd.map(lambda r: [r.id, ' '.join(x.text for x in r.anchor_text)])`